# Latex symbols in rmarkdown table using knitr::kable

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, kable

I am trying to use `knitr::kable` in Rmarkdown to create a table of latex equations. However, I am having difficulties getting special characters such as `$\sum$` or `$\hat$` to work. For example the following works:

```
knitr::kable(head(mtcars[,c(1,2)], 10),
         row.names = FALSE,
         col.names = c("Time", "$\\delta_{m}_1$"))
```

but when trying to include a hat or bar the following does not work:

```
knitr::kable(head(mtcars[,c(1,2)], 10),
         row.names = FALSE,
         col.names = c("Time", "$\\hat{m}_1$"))
```

Has anyone figured out how to embed these characters using `kable`?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome on SO! Could you please add some info about `output_format` (`html_document`, `pdf_document` or other) and `knitr` chunk options? It would be more useful to post a minimal `Rmd` file. Thanks!

Comment: The second one renders as expected when I try.

Comment: @user20650 me too. I got the first one with `"$\\delta{m}_1$"`.

Comment: Thanks all, it works when I knit it, but not when I run the code chunk in the console just with `{r echo = F} `. My mistake...