# How to display greek letters in the body of a table in R Markdown?

Tags: r, markdown

I wish to display greek letter alpha in the table generated by the following code in R Markdown. How can I do it? 
Thanks!

```
rows = 1:100

cols = c(0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001)

Q = NULL

for (a in rows){

  for (b in cols){

    q = qt(1-b, a)

    Q = append(Q,q)

  }

}

DF = data.frame(matrix(round(Q,3), ncol=8, byrow=TRUE))
DF= rbind(as.character(cols), DF)
DF = cbind(c("df/alpha",as.character(rows)), DF)

DF = unname(DF)
kable(DF)
```

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48873875/2799941), but there's not an official answer.  The issue was resolved in the comments, but the correct syntax is actually in OP's question.  Not sure if that means this is a duplicate - I'd lean towards keeping this current question open.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow @SamChang!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` notation in strings to insert LaTeX symbols, including Greek letters.  Like this:

```
DF = cbind(c("$\\alpha$",as.character(rows)), DF)
```

If you knit `kable(DF)`, you'll see alpha appear in the first column header.  Note that the symbol will not appear in the R console - you have to knit to see it.

Comment: It did work for me for html output, but not for pdf. I would like it works for pdf. Thanks.

Comment: For alpha to show in pdf, I used format = "pandoc" option, and it worked now. Thank you, Andrew!